# What is the difference between "be they" and "whether they are"?

Tags: subjunctives

> As time has gone by, we have found and accepted that dealing with problems, be they new or old ones, is always going to be a big part of our lives.

What is the difference between "be they" and "whether they are"? Would the above sentence retain its exact meaning if I used "whether they are" in place of "be they"?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. _Be they_ and _whether they are_ mean exactly the same - _be they_ is a little more formal and traditional.

Comment: The exact difference is that _be they_ is a piece of obsolete grammar, retained in this construction for rhetorical effect.

Comment: See the first answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90325/be-them-or-be-they) on English Language and Usage for the "be they" construction. ("be they new or old" is sometimes called an exhaustive conditional construction, if you want to google it.)

Comment: @ColinFine Not really obsolete, but archaic, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning, it's just other stile  expressed with archaic form of subjunctive mood. Such inversion can happen with verb "to be" when you want to substitute, for example, "whether he is smart or not" With "be he smart or not"